# How to achieve tooth selection feature in Flutter App?

Tags: flutter

I'm developing a dental app and it requires a tooth selection feature when making appointment. I'm wondering how can I be able to produce [this UI](https://www.dentistrytoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/ca86c725838176cf88b130a671d19669.jpg) in Flutter, where selected tooth will be highlighted in different color. Should I use stack to arrange every tooth one-by-one, or is there a less complex way to achieve it?

Comment: Is this for a _production system_ used by actual medical professionals? If so, it sounds like you need to do a lot more requirements-gathering and speccing-out because the stock-widgets in Flutter are simply not capable of describing dental arrangements - I guarantee you will need to do low-level visual placement, especially for handling cases like hyperdontia and hypodontia.

Comment: No, just adult teeth and baby teeth

Comment: My point is that _not everyone has 32 teeth arranged in an ideal U-shape_. Any kind of hard-coded domain-model or visual layout that's suitable for 90% of the population will fail terribly for the other 10%.

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71538797/how-to-make-a-stack-of-gesture-detectable-custom-painted-shapes/71567934#71567934) which will give you some hints on how to make irregular "buttons" in such a complex layout (you will need to convert your raster graphic to svg format for it to work)