# Creating custom shapes with ShapeBorder

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a shape like this and animate a container in it. However, every single solution I found on the internet, solves the problem with CustomPainter or CustomClipper. I don't want that. When I use these, I can't fit the containers inside this shape and can achieve what I want. Figured it out, ShapeBorder could be what I want but there isn't enough documentation for this. Can you help me to create this?

[image]

@psink

[image: This is the code and screenshot from ui]

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942533/flutter-clippath/57943257#57943257) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71538797/how-to-make-a-stack-of-gesture-detectable-custom-painted-shapes/71567934#71567934) for example (the first sample does not use null safety so you need to play with it a bit...)

Comment: note that the second sample (with `PathBorder`) is dedicated to some particular use case - the more general example is the first sample (where the `Path` is created "by hand" using `Path` class API)

Comment: @pskink I checked first one before but couldn't figure out how exactly I can give that shape. I was trying the second one now. Should I stop?

Comment: check first [MessageBorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942533/flutter-clippath/57943257#57943257) class - the other sample creates a `Path` based on svg file

Comment: @pskink for `Path getInnerPath` we can't return null, what can I do in this case.  can we skip passing path and get the desire output, using like `shape: LocShapeBorder(),`

Comment: @pskink i did but don't know how to the path i want.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh return `getOutherPath` from it (the first sample was made before "null safety")

Comment: @sonelektrikci if you dont know then use the other [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71538797/how-to-make-a-stack-of-gesture-detectable-custom-painted-shapes/71567934#71567934) (with svg data)

Comment: @pskink I tried the second solution but I can't still add another container to the shape

Comment: I added the 2. solution code but it still looks like this. I want to put green box in to the shape without stack if its possible.

Comment: @pskink I will animate that green container when data came from the server. Like battery decrease or increase animation.

Comment: I dont have an image for it but this is what I want. Like in battery animation, I want to change the green container state when new scooter battery information came from the server.  Like if the scooter's battery is green box will be shown as a whole circle, or if it's %70 then will be drawn %70. @pskink